# How to prevent gradle task to override the files created by custom task which is calling groovy class to do create file

Tags: gradle, groovy, build, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I want to append the properties after we clean and install to the install/conf directory, so the idea is to copy the existing install/conf and put it in temp directory and then call the custom task which will pick up this existing conf properties and will be updated with new properties but not overridden.

I am using one groovy class for this and putting the existing properties in map and doing putAll with new properties which is in ./conf folder.

But there is one problem when I call this custom task only it works fine and do all the changes but when I call all other task with it, like clean, copyLib and all other, it gets overridden.

I believe it is happening due to the new folder install/conf, install/lib and all, these two task are not in sync or something like that, how can I make this folder available to the newly created task. As when I changed the location of target for the properties for custom task, it worked fine with all the task as well. I also made sure that my custom task runs only after clean and other task but still no luck

```
def copyExistingConf(){
// copies the conf from install to some temp before clean runs
}

def customTask(){
 CopyConf confObject= new CopyConf("$Project_dir/conf/abc.properties", "$Project_dir/install/conf/abc.properties")
confObject.main() //I created main method which does all this putall and load
}

def copyLib(type:Copy){
from "lib" into "install/lib"
}
def clean(type:Delete){
delete "install"
}

def deploy(){
dependson =['copyLib','copyConf']
task['copyLib'].mustRunAfter('clean')
task['copyConf'].mustRunAfter('copyLib')
}
```

I could not copy the actual code but it is similar to this only

I tried running only single task in deploy and it worked but when I used any task which copy from folder to install/folder it overrode the changes.

Comment: If you cannot provide the actual code (for whatever reasons), at least ensure that your minimal example is free from (obvious) syntax errors.

Comment: Consider it is syntax free, as there is no syntax errors in my actual code, could you please tell if there is any way to solve this.